# Show that $ \left| \sum_{j=1}^{k} x_j \right|< \sqrt{k}\left \| x \right \|_2 $

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a new question, again :)

I have this task for this week, and I would like to understand it:

$ Let \binom{x_{1}}{y_{1}},...,\binom{x_{k}}{y_{k}} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\,with\,k\geq 2,and\,there\,is\,a\,j\,with\,x_j\neq x_1\\Show\,for\,x=(x_1,...,x_k) \in\mathbb{R}^{k},that\,\left | \sum_{j=1}^{k} x_j \right |< \sqrt{k}\left \| x \right \|_2 $

Can you help me with it?

Thank you in advance!
Wolfi

Comment: So what did you try? I remember when I was an undergrad, my advisor assigned this to us in our group meeting, and it was one of the first times that I started thinking deeply into college problems... this is a great problem and deserves your deep thought before asking others.

Comment: I don't see why you introduce the $y_i$...

Comment: presumably theres another part to the problem which uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Cauchy schwarz inequality by noting the left hand side is $\vec{1} \cdot \vec{x}$ where $\vec{x}$ is the vector with $x_i$ as the $i$-th component, and $\vec{1}$ is the all ones vector of the same length.

Then, $|\sum_i x_i | = | \vec{1} \cdot \vec{x} | \leq ||\vec{1}||_2 ||\vec{x}||_2 = \sqrt{k} ||\vec{x}||_2 $.

To get the strict inequality, note that $\vec{x}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\vec{1}$ since it has at least 2 different entries so the inequality is strict.